# Weird Top Gap & Not Centred CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

I have this simple HTML page that consists of 4 divs of equal height sitting ontop of each other & all centred in the middle of the page.

**My Problem:** The divs are not centred in the middle of the page & there is a padding at the top of the page for some reason.

Whats wrong with my code? How do I remove the top white gap & make the divs cented horizontally? Not that in IE, the divs are centred & not gap appears but in Safari, Firefox & Chrome the problems occur.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S9Khv/embedded/result/

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
html {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 150px 0px 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

div { 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
}


/*Main Elements*/
.homeContainer {
    width: 800px;
}

#header {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #000000; /*temporary*/
}

#mainDiv {
    height: 600px;
}

#clientDiv {
    height: 500px;
}

#footer {
    height: 600px;
    background-color: RGB(115,115,115); /*temporary*/
}
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header" class="homeContainer">
        <p>kjkj</p>
    </div>

    <div id="mainDiv" class="homeContainer">
        <p>kjkj</p>
    </div>

    <div id="clientDiv" class="homeContainer">
        <p>kjkj</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="homeContainer">
        <p>kjkj</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give the divs a margin:0 auto;

Comment: @j08691 thanks that centred it, you should make an answer so I can accept. Any ideas about the top white gap?

Comment: The top gap may be due to the default styles for the browser.  You should do a CSS reset.

Comment: jake is that gap available when embedded into your website, or are you just referring to the jsfiddle result? if you're referring to the fiddle, I think thats just the jsfiddle overlay.

Comment: @Jake M - Looks like the extra spacing came from jsFiddle. If you look at the link in my answer you'll see the gap is gone when you view the fiddle outside of an their iframe.

Comment: jsfiddle has a 10px padding all around which is why the space is there. I would also suggest setting your body to simply margin and padding 0 and then use the div margin:0 auto to center them. If you need padding on the body style a wrapper div instead of the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a forked fiddle with just the styling on the margin of the div tag changed to margin:0 auto;

Seems to fix the issues.

**[jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qdm5d/show/light/)**